# Firebird usage in big projects

Tags: firebird

What abilites have firebird to use it in highloaded projects?
Whats better PostgreSQL or FireBirdSQL?
Any one know big projects which work with Firebird database and developed over it?

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "big" or "highloaded": How many current users do you expect? What is the expected size of your DB?
Every info you provide could be helpful.

Comment: In highloaded i mean above 100+ transaction per second per 1000 online clients. We expect that DB size will grow above 2gb per 3 month.

Comment: You need to test your hardware performance too, it's not only about software.

Answer (score 10):

Both Firebird and PostgreSQL are good choices. I think 'better' is highly subjective and not easy to answer for such a broad and unspecific question. The [case-studies on firebirdsql.org](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/case-studies-catalog/) lists some projects that might be of interest to you.

It is however important to keep in mind that performance in general depends largely on the way your system interacts with the database, transaction management (and transaction configuration), underlying server etc.

Full disclosure: I am a developer of the Firebird JDBC driver, so I may be biased :)

Comment: Yes, "better" is subjective. That was the point of the question. What are the values and advantages of Firebird over PostgreSQL? I've been searching